# Using method to find an integer repeatedly

Tags: java, methods

Hello my purpose is this:
Write a method that can accept values only between 10 and 50.
Sample execution:
Enter a number between 10 and 50
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number between 10 and 50
Enter a number: 12
Number Entered: 12.
Enter a number: 0
Good Bye
So as you can see it only finishes when user enters 0.And it says different things when number is between 10 and 50 or not.I deleted again my code and started but i got stuck on some points and i gave up.My final code was:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter case number: ");
    int caseVal = scan.nextInt();

    switch(caseVal){

    case 1:

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 10 and 50");
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        betweenMethod(num);
        if(num == 0){
            System.out.println("Good Bye");
            break;
        }
        while(num != 0){
            betweenMethod(num);

        }

        break;

    case 2:

        System.out.println("Enter a number to display its divisors: ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The divisors of " + x + " are:");
        divisorsMethod(x);

        break;
    }

    scan.close();

}

public static void divisorsMethod(int a){

    if(a <= 0)
        System.out.println("The number should be greater than 0");
    else{   

    for(int b = 1; b <= a; b++){

        if(a % b == 0 && b != a)
            System.out.print(b + ", ");

        else if(b == a)
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}

public static void betweenMethod(int a){
    Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(System.in);

    if(a >= 10 && a <= 50){
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        a = inputscan.nextInt();
    }
    else if((a < 10 || a > 50) && a != 0){
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 10 and 50");
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        a = inputscan.nextInt();

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Good Bye");
    }

inputscan.close();  

}


}
```

Sorry for uncut version.It is case 1.Every time i tried it didnt work fully.If anyone can help i would appreciate it.I'm sorry if i didnt write this question in rules.(Sorry for the grammar as well)
THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK= When i type 0 it doesnt say GoodBye and end the loop.Thats where i need help.
TO EVERYONE THAT NEEDS ANSWER TOO:
I figured out what to do.Basically we say while its not equal to zero right?I wrote a new method that (after last inputscan for variable)checks if the number is zero and prints good bye.So with this way it prints good bye and it goes to starting.But it cannot do anythink else because we said while not equal to 0.Anyway thats one solution.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag as this has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Remove `inputscan.close();`, if that doesn't fix it - please explain what you mean by "didn't work".

Comment: where did you get stuck? what do you need help with?

Comment: So you choose case 1, it prompts you to enter a number, that takes you to betweenMethod which waits silently for you to enter another number,  checks the original number, prompts for you to enter a third number - and throws it away - then returns to case 1 and goes into an infinite while loop calling betweenMethod on the original 'num' number (which never changes). Yep, it doesn't work "fully" as described.

Comment: Ok i removed it and it removed the error as well.Thanks but everythink Works fine except 0 right now.When i input 0 it doesnt say Good Bye and end it.

Comment: Can you also add output of your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't `close()` `System.in`

When you call `inputscan.close()` that closes the underlying `InputStream`, which is `System.in`.

#### Return the Value

Your method should be prompting for input between two values and returning a single value. Also, you could move your `Scanner` to a `static` (or *class*) field. Something like

```
private static Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int betweenMethod(final int a, final int b) {
    int min = Math.min(a, b);
    int max = Math.max(a, b);
    while (true) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter a number between %d and %d%n", min, max);
        int in = inputscan.nextInt();
        if ((in == 0) || (in >= min && in <= max)) {
            return in;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Primitives<sup>1</sup> are Passed-By Value

You need to assign the result of the call back to your value when you loop. Something like,

```
int num = betweenMethod(10, 50);
while (num != 0) {
    System.out.printf("Number Entered: %d.%n", num);
    num = betweenMethod(num);
}
System.out.println("Good Bye");
break;
```

<sup>1<sub>**and** Everything Else in Java.</sub></sup>